# Background images of the camera do not appear in the render

Tags: camera, video, blam

I have a [footage](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cES4X1OUC08ZmHs9njAgVURt2Ic2BWpx) shot with a static camera (4K with a Pixel 2 XL front camera in case it is needed) on a tripod. I'd like to add a moving cube on fire to the scene.

As far as I understand (I'm completely new to compositing and VFX), I cannot rely on camera solving because the camera is static.

I read that the [BLAM addon](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) was the way to go. It was recently replaced by the more powerful [fspy](https://fspy.io/).

After extracting the first frame of my footage, I opened it with fspy and solved the perpective:

[image: fspy screenshot]

fspy can [export](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19AEu4_QGmuB8t2ZX-d_7jtF_LpOGD6c9) to blender with the [fspy addon](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender). This is the blender 2.8 screenshot:

[image: blender screenshot]

The image appears in the 3D view thanks to the Background images of the camera object data. Please note that it does not appear in the render.

I animated the cube and set a quick smoke simulation.

Now, how do I render the whole movie in eevee? in cycles?

Here is my blend file:

[image]

Thanks!